# onClick .hide() same DIV that's clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm `.append()`'ing some HTML via jQuery - which functions as it should. However, the function to `.detach()` (function below `// close thankyou message`) is not removing the appended HTML. No console errors...and can't seem to notice/figure out what I'm doing wrong.

How do I detach the the "thank you message" I appended when I click it? When I click it, nothing happens.

```
            // Thank You Confirmation
            // Example Modal
            var tyOverlay = 'thankyouOverlay';
            var thxMsg = 'thanksBox';

            $('.campaign-form-submit').on('click', function () {
                $('#campaign-wrap').append(                    
                    '<div id="' + tyOverlay + '">' +          
                        '<div class="' + thxMsg + ' shadow">' +
                            '<div class="ty-msg left">THANK YOU! YOUR ENTRY HAS BEEN RECEIVED.</div>' +
                            '<div class="ty-close left">' +
                                '<div class="ty-close-icon"></div>' +
                            '</div>' +    
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                    );
                $('#' + tyOverlay + ', .' + thxMsg + '').hide();
                $('#' + tyOverlay + '').fadeIn(400, function () {
                    $('.' + thxMsg + '').slideDown(200);
                });
                return false;
            });
            // close thankyou message
            $('#thankyouOverlay').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).detach();
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#thankyouOverlay` does not exist until `.campaign-form-submit` is clicked.  Either move the `#thankyouOverlay` click binding inside of the other function *or* use delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#thankyouOverlay' ...
```

Comment: I like this...
Question though - how does it not exist? When `#thankyouOverlay` is clicked, won't that function run and see that it exists in the DOM?

Comment: Also, you saying it should be like `$(document).on('click', '#thankyouOverlay', function () {...` ? I've never used this selector method.

Comment: @MikeBarwick yes you can use the same `function` that you have.  `$("#thankyouOverlay").on` is called at *binding* time.  If `#thankyouOverlay` doesn't exist when `.on` is called, the code does nothing and moves on

Answer (score 0):

try something similar to this:

```
        // Thank You Confirmation
        // Example Modal
        var tyOverlay = 'thankyouOverlay';
        var thxMsg = 'thanksBox';

        $('.campaign-form-submit').on('click', function () {
            $('#campaign-wrap').append(                    
                '<div id="' + tyOverlay + '">' +          
                    '<div class="' + thxMsg + ' shadow">' +
                        '<div class="ty-msg left">THANK YOU! YOUR ENTRY HAS BEEN RECEIVED.</div>' +
                        '<div class="ty-close left">' +
                            '<div class="ty-close-icon"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +    
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' + 
                "<script>// close thankyou message \
                    $('#thankyouOverlay').on('click', function (e) { \
                    e.preventDefault();\ 
                    $(this).detach();\
                });</script>"
                );
            $('#' + tyOverlay + ', .' + thxMsg + '').hide();
            $('#' + tyOverlay + '').fadeIn(400, function () {
                $('.' + thxMsg + '').slideDown(200);
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! not sure I'm a fan of appending a `<script>`...hmm

Comment: By appending script, I meant that your javascript code must get placed in correct time ;) me neither :P